# Change html attributes with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this HTML code

```
<div id="meta-8" class="widget col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 widget_meta "><div class="widget-wrap">
```

What I want to do is... I want to change it using PHP pregreplace, so it become:

```
<div id="meta-8" class="widget col-md-4 widget_meta "><div class="widget-wrap">
```

Maybe the code will be like this

```
$output = preg_replace("RegEx", "col-md-4 widget_meta", $string);
```

But, I'm not familiar with RegEx.. Could someone help me please?

Comment: @UglyEddie hmmm... [jquery?](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: The question is why do you want do it? Maybe there is a better solution and yes - jQuery is nice - but not a solution for everything. And obviously not the best solution for someone that tries to change HTML with PHP - looks more like a lack of knowledge.

Comment: Are you simply trying to replace all col-* classes to a single col-md-4 class?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this for **regex** way but i suggest you to do it with using [**`html parser`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

```
$html='<div id="meta-8" class="widget col-md-4 widget_meta "><div class="widget-wrap">';
preg_replace("~(?<=class=")([^"]*)~", "widget col-md-4 widget_meta", $input_lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [w3cSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) you can use this easy javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('meta-8').setAttribute('class','widget col-md-4 widget_meta');
```

As I said in my comment, I do not know why you want do it - so this is a solution. And I would not use jQuery just to do this. Maybe you could explain more why you want change it with PHP.

Comment: `getElementsById` ? id is a unique IDentifier. there is no getElement**s**ById and clearly not the way to go

Comment: @Sharky holy god - it was a typo/copypaste, thanks! And next time just edit the answer and everything is good.